# TypeScript compiler error for Enum in Switch statement

Tags: typescript, enums, switch-statement

Why does the TypeScript compilier (version 2.7.2) show the error message "*error TS2678: Type 'Enum1.b' is not comparable to type 'Enum1.a'*" for the following code sequence?

```
const enum Enum1 {a, b};

let e1: Enum1 = Enum1.a;

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   const newE1 = (i % 2 == 0) ? Enum1.a : Enum1.b;
   setE1(newE1);
   switch (e1) {
      case Enum1.a:
         console.log("a");
         break;
      case Enum1.b:
         console.log("b");
         break;
   }
}

function setE1 (newE1: Enum1) {
   e1 = newE1;
}
```

When I replace `switch(e1)` with `switch(+e1)`, the error does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplification :

```
const enum Enum1 {a, b};
let e1: Enum1 = Enum1.a;

setE1(Enum1.b);
// Error === cannot be applied to Enum1.a and Enum1.b
if (e1 === Enum1.b) console.log('yup'); // But it is

function setE1(newE1: Enum1) {
   e1 = newE1;
}
```

Seems like a bug in the inference engine. You should report it here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: Thanks, I have reported it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22108)

Comment: I have found another workaround: `let e1: number = Enum1.a;` instead of `let e1: Enum1 = Enum1.a;`

Comment: Another workaround: `let e1: Enum1 = <Enum1>Enum1.a;` or `let e1 = <Enum1>Enum1.a;`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `switch` expression in a function with typed parameter, this works as expected.

Example:

```
const enum Enum1 {a, b};

function testSwitch(e1: Enum1) {
    switch (e1) {
        case Enum1.a:
            console.log("a");
            break;
        case Enum1.b:
            console.log("b");
            break;
    }
}

testSwitch(Enum1.a)
```

will compile  and output `a`